# How can I use case statement in computed column in Oracle database

Tags: sql, oracle

Can I use Case statement in computed column in Oracle.

I have filename column in table which can be used to populate source of data. 
eg. if filename contains *abc* than source system is ABC, if filename contains *def* then source of data is DEF.

I need to alter the table with new column *source* (which should be computed from existing file name column)

Comment: have you tried?

Comment: Pretty sure the answer is yes, but can you be more specific about what kind of computed column?

Comment: Show your "bad" SQL.

Comment: @GaurangPopat . . . Assuming that the `case` expression only references columns in the current row.

Comment: Guys, I have added more details on above question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do that. For example:

```
CREATE TABLE TEST_TAB
  (N1     NUMBER,
   S2     VARCHAR2(10) GENERATED ALWAYS AS (CASE
                                              WHEN N1 IS NULL THEN 'NULL'
                                              WHEN N1 < 0 THEN 'NEGATIVE'
                                              WHEN N1 = 0 THEN 'ZERO'
                                              WHEN N1 > 0 THEN 'POSITIVE'
                                            END));
```

[dbfiddle here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=5596e3682e8c21e6f0c0e7dbd0f91f67)