# database foreignkey chaining

Tags: sql, oracle, foreign-keys

How can I create a constraint that references columns in two other tables at the same time?

```sql
Table A {
  int id PK
  int name
}

Table B {
  int id PK
  int A_id FK Nullable
}

Table C {
  int id PK
  int A_id FK Nullable
}

Table D {
  int id PK
  int B_id FK Not Null
  int C_id FK Not Null
  -- TODO A_id constraints B and C
}
```

Given the above schema, I need to create a constraint for table D that indirectly references the id column of table A. The constraint should check if:

1. A_id from table B exists, use it.
2. Otherwise, if A_id from table C exists, use it.
3. Otherwise, insert Null.

I've tried using the following query to achieve this:

```sql
SELECT (CASE WHEN B.A_id IS NOT NULL THEN B.A_id
            WHEN C.A_id IS NOT NULL THEN C.A_id
            ELSE NULL
       END) AS A_id
FROM B, C, D
WHERE D.B_id = B.id AND D.C_id = C.id
```

However, the database is too large to rely on this query. Is there a better way to create this constraint? Please help me.

Comment: Hi , what about View will that work or you can use Computed columns, check this link for the example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58288330/how-can-i-use-case-statement-in-computed-column-in-oracle-database

Comment: It's not possible to reference two tables in FK constraint (and it's not possible to set FK reference to non-unique column, which is the case for A_id in TableB and TableC). Either do these checks at the application side or compute column on a query time.

Comment: You could copy the correct A_id in table D from a trigger, a computed column would not work because of the restrictions on what can be referenced in the expression.

Comment: I'd advise you to have two columns in table D, one having foreign key to table B and the other foreign key to table C. And, if needed, ad a check constraint like check((column_d1 is not null and column_d2 is null) or (column_d1 is null and column_d2 is not null) or (column_d1 is null and column_d2 is null)) as to check that not both columns are filled-in, if so be the requirement. Otherwise, what you asked for can't be obtained via constraints in database, but only in stored procedure or trigger.